# Using a datetime as filename and parse the filename afterwards?

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io, datetime-format

I am writing files to my harddrive,The filename is build like this:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss}.txt", DateTime.Now)
```

So the filename is "2010-09-20_09-47-04.txt" for example. Now I want to show those filenames in a dropdown, but with another format. The format should be dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss. How can I do that, or is there a better approach?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this on console and it did the job.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim enUS As New CultureInfo("en-US")
    Dim d As String = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss")
    Dim da As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss", enUS)
    Console.WriteLine("Date from filename: {0}", d)
    Console.WriteLine("Date formated as date: {0}", Format(da, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

End Sub
End Module
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you want 24-hour time, uppercase the `hh` part.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the same format you use to build name to parse the file name into DateTime object and than convert it to the desired format with [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Comment: That's a good idea. Alternately, `TryParseExact` might be a good idea, unless you really want to throw on failure here.

Comment: Parse/ParseExact dont seem to work with my format...I need the time as well.

Comment: @grady - ParseExact should return time as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it back into a `DateTime`, then format it to your display format.

Answer (score 1):

```
string FileName = "2010-09-20_09-47-04";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Parse(FileName.Substring(0, 10));
dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, but Giorgi's suggestion about `ParseExact` is correct.

Comment: @Steven - Ah yes, TryParseExact slipped my mind. That would be a better option.  Thanks

Comment: `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` have the nice benefit of failing if the input is a valid date in an unexpected format. However, which of these two you want to use will depend on whether have an exception thrown is the best way to handle that failure.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your filename using a regular expression:

```
Regex r = new Regex("(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).txt");
Match m = r.Match(fileName);
```

**Update:** The DateTime.Parse approach proposed by others is much more appropriate.

Since you are working with dates, you might want to consider using the created date or modified date of the file instead?

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
string title = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", f.CreationTime);
```

Comment: We need a Society for the Protection of Regular Expressions, to defend them from this kind of abuse. ;-)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't consider this as abuse, if you suppose you have a string as input and need to parse it for a date. It's just that DateTime already provides it. Who knows whether they use Regex behind the scenes?

Comment: They don't. But even if they did, that would not be a good reason for us to do it. :-)