# Parse DateTime From FileName

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to develop a utility to manage large sets of backup's:

I have my backups structured like:

```
D:\SQLBACKUP\NOFAULT2010\Datatbase\LOG\NOFAULT2010_Datatbase_LOG_20110906_182000.trn
D:\SQLBACKUP\NOFAULT2010\Datatbase\LOG\NOFAULT2010_Database_LOG_20110906_183000.trn
```

I can get rid of the static parts easily enough

```
Replace(@"D:\SQLBACKUP\NOFAULT2010\Datatbase\LOG\NOFAULT2010_Datatbase_LOG_", "").Replace(".trn", "");
```

How can I consistently parse this part 20110906_182000 ... I'm open to any other suggestions.  Thanks My brain is on vacation today something terrible.

Comment: Link for future Googlers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749516/using-a-datetime-as-filename-and-parse-the-filename-afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse out hour, minutes, seconds, etc. with Substring() and then use `new DateTime()` to create an instance of the date class.

An alternative is to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

Comment: Duh, ! Wow I'm in orbit today thank you ... Will mark as answer

Comment: There's also `.ParseExact()` which I believe throws an exception - if that's your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the DateTime part of the filename and parse it.

```
var path = @"D:\SQLBACKUP\NOFAULT2010\Datatbase\LOG\NOFAULT2010_Datatbase_LOG_20110906_182000.trn";
var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                   // assuming you have a consistent format with a fixed length
var datetimePart = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 15);
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    datetimePart, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

p.s., When working with path strings, always use the [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to manipulate them.  Don't use regular string manipulation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you don't actually need to use substring or string parsing.

```
        DateTime parsedFileDate;

        string FileFullPath = @"D:\SQLBACKUP\NOFAULT2010\Datatbase\LOG\NOFAULT2010_Database_LOG_20110906_183000.trn";
        string FileNameFormat = "'NOFAULT2010_Database_LOG_'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'.trn'";

        DateTime.TryParseExact(Path.GetFileName(FileFullPath), FileNameFormat, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedFileDate);

        Console.WriteLine($"Parsed date: {parsedFileDate}");

        Console.ReadLine();
```